# How to use Flutter (StreamBuilder) query with Firestore rules?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a admin app and a user app. All data go in one database and I want to make sure that admin have only permission to ready there own users and not from other admins. So my solution was to give the admin a id and if the admin create a new user in the software, the user will get the same id (not userID just a random id for "assignment").

Firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    //User
    match /Users/{userID}{
      allow create: if false;
      allow delete, write: if isUserOfAdmin(userID);
      allow read: if isUserOwner(userID);
      allow update: if isValidUserRequest(); 

      function isUserOwner(userID){
        return isUserOfAdmin(userID) || isLoggedInUser();
      }

      function isUserOfAdmin(userID){
        return isLoggedInUserAdmin() && (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(userID)).data.adminID == getAdminIDofLoggedInAdmin());
      }
      function getAdminIDofLoggedInAdmin(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Admins/$(request.auth.uid)).data.adminID;
      }

      function isLoggedInUser(){
        return isUserLoggedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)) != null;
      }
      function isLoggedInUserAdmin(){
        return isUserLoggedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Admins/$(request.auth.uid)) != null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Important here is the `allow read:`.

In admin software:

```
body: SafeArea(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: firebase.getAdminID(),
    builder: (context1, snapshot1) {
      final adminID = snapshot1.data;
      print(adminID.toString() + " snapshot 3");
      if (snapshot1.hasData) {
        print(adminID.toString() + " snapshot 4");
        return StreamBuilder(
             stream:
                 base
                .collection('Users')
                .where('adminID', isEqualTo: adminID)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

The Error:
`[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Side note, in PlayGround of Firebase Firestore rules, my request is working.
I rename some functions/methods etc. so maybe I read over some renaming.
The prints proved that the adminID was requested.

Struggling 3 days with help from friends but no solution yet. I would be really thankful about some help.

Comment: found out that maybe the "allow read" (Firestore rules) is the main problem.

Comment: I am using flutter web and I tested it on iOS now and there its working. Do it means that in flutter web the query is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The rules are the problem. I had to use `resource.data.adminID` instead of `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(userID)).data.adminID`

With `get` you can search for a specific thing everywhere in the database.
With `resource` you search in the path ( for my example match `/Users/{userID}{}`) and firebase is looking once for the adminID in every doc.

Simple as that xD

Comment: I have same problem. but your saying to use `resource.data.adminID` , but **what if we have to use `get()` to fetch data from other path?** Currently I am using flutter streambuilder, and getting same error,but it worked in PlayGround.

Comment: I don't know your Data structure. If you don't find any way maybe change data structure because this is the problem. 

Possibilities: 
- for stream builder use .snapshot()
- if rules are the problem (permission) your path is wrong or
- you have to change the firestore rules so you have access to the data
- maybe your rules are wrong and you have to use resource in your rules instead of get()

Comment: yes, you are correct. by the way my problem was with "+" of phone_number in get() path.